# Styling a checkbox label with CSS3

Tags: css, label, stylesheet

I have styled a checkbox using CSS3 and this is working (by hiding the checkbox and putting/styling a label over it). Now I have found some CSS3 created icons which I want to use for my checkbox. Since the checkbox is styled using CSS3, I though it would be simple to use the with CSS3 created icons for the checkbox.

Well... I thought it would be easy, but I am unsuccessful doing so.

The CSS3 created icons are sound icons. One with "sound on" and one with "sound off". Now I want the "sound on" icon to be used when the checkbox is checked, and the "sound off" when it's unchecked.

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/TRtvx/

**This is what I've tried:**

Basically `input:checked + label:before` should have the `.volume-on:before` style. This worked and I saw the "sound waves" in my button div. Unfortunaly I couldn't see the rest of the icon anymore (the cone).

Is what I want even possible? And how to accomplish this?

Kind regards,

Comment: You should be using radio buttons not checkboxes

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to do - are you trying to only show one sound icon at a time?

Comment: @antonpug Yes, checked = with sound waves, unchecked = with out. So in theory when checked, it should only add the sound waves

Comment: I use checkboxes since there are more options to select. With radio you can just select 1 in a form

Comment: Basically you want to *replace* the real checkbox control with the volume icon, is that right?

Comment: @antonpug I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @BoltClock yes, it should still work as a checkbox of course

Comment: Are you open to changes in your markup, or is it fixed?

Comment: @BoltClock Everything about the label/checkbox you can change, the blue button div must stay as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS Sprites to achieve this - basically you would be showing different parts of a single image, acting as two images. Check out this great tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: I could do that, putting an image in the label, but that is a last resort if the CSS3 is not possible